# ImageIO.read() can't read some images

Tags: java, image, java-8, javax.imageio

I have a GIF image and try to read it into BufferedImage.

```
public class ImageReadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        f(new File("/Users/hieugioi/Downloads/Photos/butterfly.gif"));
    }

    public static void f(File file) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
    }

}
```

It shows errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.read(RandomAccessFile.java:377)
    at javax.imageio.stream.FileImageInputStream.read(FileImageInputStream.java:117)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.gif.GIFImageReader.getCode(GIFImageReader.java:351)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.gif.GIFImageReader.read(GIFImageReader.java:950)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1308)
    at com.hieutest.ImageReadTest.f(ImageReadTest.java:16)
    at com.hieutest.ImageReadTest.main(ImageReadTest.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

The "butterfly" image got from [this open source project](https://code.google.com/archive/p/imagetestsuite/downloads):

[image]

It succeeds with other regular images but it fails with this image. Is it image problem or API bug?

Comment: [ImageIO.read() throws IndexOutOfBoundsException on certain bad GIF file](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6687967) ... doesn't help, but at least you're not alone

Comment: I opened the file in Photoshop and saved it again (to a seperate file as a gif) and it read file. There's something about the way that particular image  has been encoded which Java doesn't like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is know JDK bug see:

- [IndexOutOfBoundsException calling ImageIO.read() on malformed PNG](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6945174)
- [ImageIO.read() throws IndexOutOfBoundsException on certain bad GIF file](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6687967)
- [JDK-6967419 : IndexOutOfBoundsException when drawing PNGs](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6967419)

These bug are fixed in Java 9.

Comment: Thanks but that bug is about drawing image, not reading.
"When drawing PNG images to a ServletOutputStream using the following method javax.imageio.ImageIO.write"

Comment: See the other one there are multiple bug related to this topic.

Comment: The GIF bug still seems to have status OPEN/Unresolved... :-( I was actually surprised to see bugs fixed in Java 9, these bugs has been open for a long time...

Comment: the bug does not seem to have been fixed even till now from above-mentioned links. Additionally, I'm using jdk1.11 but the bug still exists.

Answer (score 2):

I just found a solution for this problem presented on this page: http://web.archive.org/web/20200805050306/http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=53328

**Solution:**
By using the ImageIcon Class you can read a gif file and then draw it into a newly created BufferedImage.

The full code of the solution by http://web.archive.org/web/20200805050306/http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=53328:

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.image.*;
 import javax.swing.*;

 public class BuffIt {
 public static void main (String args[]) {
     // Get Image
     ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(args[0]);
     Image image = icon.getImage();

     // Create empty BufferedImage, sized to Image
     BufferedImage buffImage = 
       new BufferedImage(
           image.getWidth(null), 
           image.getHeight(null), 
           BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);//you can use any type

     // Draw Image into BufferedImage
     Graphics g = buffImage.getGraphics();
     g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

     // Show success
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(buffImage));
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);
    frame.pack();
    frame.show();
  }
}
```